# Large cursive letters

Tags: math-mode, fonts, typography

I want to write a large cursive a as in the following picture:[image]

Is this possible? And if so how it is done?

Answer (score 3):

> Is this possible? And if so how it is done?

I take it that you wish to access a set of math-caligraphic letters with an uppercase letter "A" that has a round rather than a pointed "top". Searching the list of alphabets shown on pages 8 to 10 of the user guide of the [mathalpha](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha) package, one notices immediately that there aren't a lot of fonts that feature an uppercase letter "A" with a rounded top. Indeed, there's just one: the "curly script" font of the [MathTime Professional II](https://pctex.com/mtpro2.html) group of math fonts. This math font isn't free of charge; however, it isn't super-expensive either -- unlike some other math font packages out there. (Aside: The so-called "lite" subset of the `mtpro2` package is, in fact, free of charge. What you'll need for this exercise is the full set, not just the lite subset, of the package.)

Once you've downloaded and installed/activated the full `mtpro2` package, you should run either

```
\usepackage[mtpccal]{mtpro2}
```

or

```
\usepackage[cal=mtc]{mathalfa} % 'mathalpha' works too...
```

in the preamble to access the "curly" caligraphic letters. Then, access these letters in the body of the document by typing `\mathcal{A}`, `\mathcal{B}`, etc -- while in math mode, in case this isn't obvious.

A final comment: The `mtpro2` package works best under pdfLaTeX.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mtpccal]{mtpro2}
%\usepackage[cal=mtc]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{ABC}\dots\mathcal{KLMNO}\dots\mathcal{XYZ}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can use any desktop script font as your `\mathscr` font:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
% Set up your other fonts here.
\setmathfont{SomeScriptFont}[range=scr, Scale=MatchUppercase]
```

If you also need `\mathbfscr`, add:

```
\setmathfont{SomeScriptFont Bold}[range=bfscr, Scale=MatchUppercase]
```

You could also set `\mathcal` separately.

Comment: +1. I'm keeping my fingers crossed that the OP will see fit to weigh in and provide information as to whether they're interested in a very specific script font face -- *viz.*, one in which the uppercase script letter "A" has a round rather than a pointy top -- or if *any* script-style font will do. If it's the latter, my answer could be simplified/generalized greatly as well...

Comment: @Mico They appear to want to duplicate a paper of which they have a scan, not a PDF.